# Using xarray interp to reproject a dataarray?

Tags: raster, python-xarray, map-projections

I have looked a lot at the xarray documentation of [the interp function](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/interpolation.html#example) and I cannot really make sense of it. I see it is a reprojection but it doesn't really fit a real case example.
Is their someone that could make sense of it for example by reprojecting this dataset on a webmercator datum?

#### Something like the example:

```py
import xarray as xr
from pyproj import Transformer

ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature").isel(time=0)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4))
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(ds.lon, ds.lat)
shp = lon.shape
# reproject the grid
gcs_to_3857 = Transformer.from_crs(4326, 3857, always_xy=True)
x, y = gcs_to_3857.transform(lon.ravel(), lat.ravel())
# future index for a regular raster
X= np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), shp[1])
Y= np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), shp[0])   
data["x"] = xr.DataArray(np.reshape(x, shp), dims=("lat", "lon"))
data["y"] = xr.DataArray(np.reshape(y, shp), dims=("lat", "lon"))
```

#### And here, I am stuck

Should be something like `ds.interp(x=X,y=Y)` but the array is indexed on lat lon

It is all a bit confusing to me...

Comment: would using [rioxarray's reproject](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject.html) work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea is something like this:

```py
In [1]: import xarray as xr
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: from pyproj import Transformer
   ...:
   ...: ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature").isel(time=0)
```

design a target grid *in transformed space*:

```py
In [2]: # find the new bounds in mercator space
   ...: gcs_to_3857 = Transformer.from_crs(4326, 3857, always_xy=True)
   ...: x, y = gcs_to_3857.transform(
   ...:     [ds.lon.min(), ds.lon.max()],
   ...:     [ds.lat.min(), ds.lat.max()],
   ...: )

In [3]: # design a target grid for the re-projected data - can be any dims you want
   ...: X = np.linspace(x[0], x[1], 500)
   ...: Y = np.linspace(y[0], y[1], 600)
   ...: XX, YY = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
```

Transform this grid back into lat/lon

```py
In [4]: # build a reverse transformer from Mercator back to lat/lons
   ...: merc_to_latlng = Transformer.from_crs(3857, 4326, always_xy=True)
   ...: new_lons, new_lats = merc_to_latlng.transform(XX.ravel(), YY.ravel())
   ...: new_lons = new_lons.reshape(XX.shape)
   ...: new_lats = new_lats.reshape(YY.shape)
```

Create new DataArrays to index the lat/lon values corresponding to the grid points on the target grid (indexed by x and y in Mercator space):

```py
In [5]: # create arrays indexed by (x, y); also convert lons back to (0, 360)
   ...: new_lons_da = xr.DataArray((new_lons % 360), dims=["y", "x"], coords=[Y, X])
   ...: new_lats_da = xr.DataArray(new_lats, dims=["y", "x"], coords=[Y, X])
```

Use xarray's advanced indexing to interpolate the data to the new points *while* re-indexing onto the new grid

```py
In [6]: ds_mercator = ds.interp(lon=new_lons_da, lat=new_lats_da, method="linear")
```

Now the data is indexed by x and y, with points equally spaced *in Mercator space*:

```py
In [7]: ds_mercator
Out[7]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (y: 600, x: 500)
Coordinates:
    time     datetime64[ns] 2013-01-01
    lon      (y, x) float64 200.0 200.3 200.5 200.8 ... 329.2 329.5 329.7 330.0
    lat      (y, x) float64 15.0 15.0 15.0 15.0 15.0 ... 75.0 75.0 75.0 75.0
  * y        (y) float64 1.689e+06 1.708e+06 1.727e+06 ... 1.291e+07 1.293e+07
  * x        (x) float64 -1.781e+07 -1.778e+07 ... -3.369e+06 -3.34e+06
Data variables:
    air      (y, x) float64 nan nan nan nan nan ... 237.3 237.6 238.0 238.3 nan
Attributes:
    Conventions:  COARDS
    title:        4x daily NMC reanalysis (1948)
    description:  Data is from NMC initialized reanalysis\n(4x/day).  These a...
    platform:     Model
    references:   http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.ncep.reanaly...
```

The new projection can be seen in the axes (and distortion) of the transformed (right) as compared to the original (left) datasets:

```py
In [8]: fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14, 5))
   ...: ds.air.plot(ax=axes[0])
   ...: ds_mercator.air.plot(ax=axes[1])
Out[8]: <matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh at 0x2b3b94be0
```

[image: Air temperature in PlateCarree (left) and reprojected to Mercator (right)]

Comment: This is brilliant, you should get that into the docs of xarray, this is so useful and a real-case example!

Answer (score 5):

You could also use reproject from `rioxarray` as suggested.
Here is the code:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature').isel(time=0)
ds = ds.rio.write_crs('EPSG:4326')
dst = ds.rio.reproject('EPSG:3857', shape=(250, 250), resampling=Resampling.bilinear, nodata=np.nan)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14, 5))
ds.air.plot(ax=ax[0])
dst.air.plot(ax=ax[1])
```

[image]

Comment: This is an excellent use of rasterio and simple at that. I have read their doc and I could not figure out how to do this basic reprojection. Another snippet they should add to their documentation! Thanks a lot !

Comment: I have tested your code and it doesn't work for me
`AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'rio'`

Comment: OK, I needed to update to a more recent xarray version